# Div not displaying over video

Tags: css, html, html5-video

I have few simple divs and a video as a background:

```
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                        <video width="1024" height="704" id="vid" loop>
                            <source src="images/reverse.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        </video>
                        <div id="overlay">
                            <img src="images/man.png" id="man-photo"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>


        #vid {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #overlay {
            position: absolute;
            display:block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            z-index: 1000;
        }
        #man-photo {
            position: absolute;
            top: 200px;
            left: 300px;
            z-index: 1200;
            display: block;
        }
```

All are inside a indagerous swiper slide.
The video is shown correctly, image is positioned correctly but its not visible!
First time such thing ever happened to me: when I inspect it in developer tools and change any of its property, suddenly it gets drawn as expected.

Any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: Create a JSfiddle, I'm pretty sure this code does not reflect what your saying.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gjHVK/   in a fiddle it works correctly. I cant post the app code so i have just no clue

Comment: We cant fix the code if the code you provide works. You have to include all relative code for us to see, recreate the problem and then update your question. Until then we cant help.

Comment: As i said this is impossible. So i will have to work on it on my own. I will just add, that when i resize chrome dev tools the image appears on appropriate position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently chrome has some problems with redrawing images over video.

But:

```
setInterval(function(){$('#man-photo').hide().show(0)},100);
```

fixed it.
Not the tidiest solution but it is working.